# make: don't know how to make install. Stop установка nodejs

Tags: веб-сервер

Появилась проблема. Вообщем установил я nodejs в /usr/ports/www, а потом удалил папку node, ну удалить nodejs так хотел. Ну так удалил. Хочу заного установить, пишет:

> make: don't know how to make install.Stop

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# cd

# portsnap fetch

# portsnap extract

# cd /usr/ports/www/node

# make install clean

Answer (score 1):

Выйдите с этого порта в другую какую-нибудь директорию и потом заново выполните команду.

Comment: @tehnikpc, как это сделать? Скажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: make clean ?

Comment: @pyatak, montytool# cd /usr/ports/www/nodemontytool# make cleanmake: don't know how to make clean. Stop

Comment: Сделайте например так "cd /" и потом уже "make BATCH=yes -C /usr/ports/www/node/ install clean"

Comment: @tehnikpc, montytool# cd /montytool# make BATCH=yes -C /usr/ports/www/node install cleanmake: don't know how to make install. Stop

Comment: Сделайте "portsnap fetch extract" и попробуйте заново.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала попробуйте выполнить

```
$ ./configure
```

После просто

```
$ make
```

вследствие чего выкачаются и будут установлены все отсутствующие зависимости.
В конце

```
$ make install clean
```

Должно сработать.